# Cleaner loop through multidimensional array in php

Tags: php

Let's say you have a multidimensional array like so and assume it won:

```
$Call = array(
    "Foo1" => array(
        "Bar1" => array(
            "Baz1", 
            "Baz2"
        )
    ), 
    "Foo2", 
    "Foo3" => array(
        "Bar2", 
        "Bar3"
    )
);
```

How would you echo Every Foo, Bar and Baz in the array? I'm particularly having an issue due to Foo2 being set key of 0, so I need to somehow workaround the key being set on values that are not keys.

My current solution, although works, feels too cheat and was wondering if there's cleaner way to loop through the array:

```
    foreach ($Call as $key => $value) {

            echo "1.".(is_array($value) ? $key : $value)."<br>";

        if(is_array($value)){

            foreach ($value as $key => $value) {

                echo "a.".(is_array($value) ? $key : $value)."<br>";

                if(is_array($value)){

                    foreach ($value as $key => $value) {

                        echo "A.".(is_array($value) ? $key : $value)."<br>";

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the expected output for the input you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a clean code using recursion I have following solution.

```
$Call= array("Foo1" => array("Bar1" => array("Baz1", "Baz2")), "Foo2", "Foo3" => array("Bar2", "Bar3"));
cleanloop($Call);
function cleanloop($arr){
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            echo $key . "<br/>";
            cleanloop($value);
        }else{
            echo $value . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

I hope with a little more effort, listing / numbering can be managed. using html buitl in numbering I can update like

```
function cleanloop($arr){
    echo "<ol>";
    foreach($arr as $key => $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            echo "<li>";
            echo $key;
            cleanloop($value);
            echo "</li>";
        }else{
            echo "<li>" . $value . "</li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ol>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of taste, but I do not like recursion.

The [SPL iterators](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) provide all you need:

```
<?php
$Call = array(
    "Foo1" => array(
        "Bar1" => array(
            "Baz1",
            "Baz2"
        )
    ),
    "Foo2",
    "Foo3" => array(
        "Bar2",
        "Bar3"
    )
);
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($Call), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
for ($iterator->rewind(); $iterator->valid(); $iterator->next()) {
    echo 'Depth: ';
    echo $iterator->getDepth();
    echo ' Key: ';
    echo $iterator->key();
    echo ' Content: ';
    echo is_array($iterator->current()) ? 'Array' : $iterator->current();
    echo '; ' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Please have a look at the [constructor of the RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.construct.php). It provides some useful flags.